# Winform tab control with single ui

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I am developing a Winforms application where I need to use tabs. All tabs have the same UI (it will only change the content of text fields). Is it possible to create one template for all tabs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the UI is the same across all tabs, then you simply need to inform a view that the model is changing. Remove data bindings to old model and add data bindings to new model.

Another way would be to create a single `UserControl`. Each tab can reference it's own instance of the control and each control has it's own model to which it binds.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom control that has all the controls on it that you need and then add the custom control to each tab page.